# SharePoint 2010 a single user is facing search issues in SharePoint List

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-search

A user is not getting any result from SharePoint search while searching  any list item. In a SharePoint site a user is trying to search list items, he is getting nothing in search result for any item search.

He is getting results for all other type of search like people or other site content.

Except this user rest others have no issue with searching those list items.
User have sufficient rights on Site and List. Any lead will help me a lot.

Comment: Is user is new user or old user?

Comment: He is new for this particular site but not new for entire intranet site. The day i have given him access rights to the site since that day itself he never gets any search result when tries to search of any list items of this site.

Comment: he is having design rights. I have given same rights to one of my colleague and tested that she is able to search items. i don't know whats wrong with that specific user.

Comment: Is your search crawl working? Try the full crawl and then check.

Comment: If crawl is not happened after giving him access, he will not able to search the items.

Comment: I understand that without crawl he won't be able to search.This issue is since 1 month..Meanwhile many times Full crawl has been happened. I also did one manual full crawl.If this is some how related to crawl than how come others are able to search.Even people who got added after this user they can also  search.

Comment: This is strange. Have you tried re-indexing?

Comment: It is SharePoint 2010 so re-indexing option is not available. I just have Reset-Index option in Search Administrator in Central admin...But i am afraid of using this, as i am not sure what problem it can create as it is production site

Answer (score 0):

Adding this user into the admin group, then compare the results.

If he can get results after he is added into the admin group, then this is a permission issue. Mostly because he is not correctly granted permission.

If still he cannot get any results, you can try to use Fiddler Tool to monitor requests and responses to see what is failing when he is doing a search.

Comment: Should fiddler be installed where i am using the site or it should be installed into the application server?

Comment: You can refer to below article: https://www.dynatrace.com/support/help/how-to-use-dynatrace/real-user-monitoring/setup-and-configuration/web-applications/troubleshooting/capture-https-sessions-for-debugging-using-fiddler/